# why return behaves differently here in java?

Tags: java, return

The return statement in the below code gives me compilation error "Missing Return Statement", where as if i put atlast as single statement it works. what is wrong with my understanding here. please help?

This code gives me "Missing return statement" error at last line.

```
private static String MixStrings(String str1, String str2) {
    String finalString = "", trimmedString = "", restofStrings = "";

    String[] s1 = str1.split("");
    String[] s2 = str2.split("");

    if (str1.length() > str2.length()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {
            finalString = finalString + s1[i] + s2[i];
        }

        return finalString + str1.substring(str2.length());
    } else if (str1.length() < str2.length()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
            finalString = finalString + s1[i] + s2[i];
        }

        return finalString + str2.substring(str1.length());
    }
}
```

This code does not show any error and works fine.

```
private static String MixStrings(String str1, String str2) {
    String finalString = "", trimmedString = "", restofStrings = "";

    String[] s1 = str1.split("");
    String[] s2 = str2.split("");

    if (str1.length() > str2.length()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {
            finalString = finalString + s1[i] + s2[i];
        }

        finalString = finalString + str1.substring(str2.length());
    } else if (str1.length() < str2.length()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
            finalString = finalString + s1[i] + s2[i];
        }

        finalString = finalString + str2.substring(str1.length());
    }

    return finalString;
}
```

Comment: In your first snippet - what should compiler do when no if case is executed? Shall it guess what needs to be done?

Comment: In the first snippet, your code doesn't have an unconditional return statement, so if neither IF is triggered, it will have nothing to do.

Comment: @michalk, got it. i understand now that i am missing the what if both strings are equal. i voted your answer too and thanks for others too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case that `str1` and `str2` are equal in length, you do not have a `return` statement. Insert an `if` block that accounts for `str1` and `str2` being equal in length.

Comment: got it. i understand now that i am missing the logic of what if both strings are equal. i voted and accepted your answer. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Your first code only returns in the two cases which may both be false at the same time.

You must cover all cases, use an `else` block, or return after the `if/else`.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example you do not have a branch for the condition where the lengths of the two strings are equal. Therefore there is no guarantee that you will encounter a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code, you added two if conditions that mean if any one of them is true then it will return the case.

But if both are false that means the function does n't return anything. Which is wrong.

So you need to add the return statement in the last after the if.

Like this:

```
private static String MixStrings(String str1, String str2) {
    String finalString = "", trimmedString = "", restofStrings = "";

    String[] s1 = str1.split("");
    String[] s2 = str2.split("");

    if (str1.length() > str2.length()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) {
            finalString = finalString + s1[i] + s2[i];
        }

        return finalString + str1.substring(str2.length());
    } else if (str1.length() < str2.length()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {
            finalString = finalString + s1[i] + s2[i];
        }

        return finalString + str2.substring(str1.length());
    }

return "Youe value";    // here is the return if both `if` false

}
```